# Binding to List<string> not updating the corresponding strings

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have the following XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        x:Name="window"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="327" Width="213" 
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>          
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding TheString}" />
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Grid.Row="2">Check strings</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Pretty simple. Now here's my code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public List<string> Strings { get; } = new List<string> { "Hello world1", "Hello world2", "Hello world3" };

    public string TheString { get; set; } = "Helloo";

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", this.Strings) + $"\n\n{this.TheString}");
    }
}
```

The problem is if I update the string values in the `Strings` list from the UI, it never gets updated when I click the button. What am I doing wrong?
I am correctly binding the `Listbox`'s `ItemsSource` to the `Strings` List. I am also correctly binding the `TextBox` in the `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: A reach but add mode=twoway to the TextBox

Comment: Default mode for TextBox is twoWay, However you have no setter for your List. If there is no Setter I think your collection will be readonly hence you cannot update it.

Comment: @Bearcat9425, I am not updating the collection itself tho, I am just updating it's members, which can be done with a getter only property as well

Comment: Did you try not DataContext on the grid?

Comment: If the Collection is read only then so are its members.  Try putting set; in there and see if it works for you.

Comment: @Frisbee, yes. I included it by mistake, fixed now. Removing double DataContext still has no effect.

Comment: @Bearcat9425, putting setter does not work either. 
P.S Making it getter only means that the reference cannot point to another object once assigned inside Constructor (Or outside in the class in the static context) The object itself can still be altered by using it's member properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is about the immutability of `string`. When you change the text in `TextBox` you create a new `string`, the old one does not change. Therefore List always contain the same values.

To update it you should wrap it in a class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged and fire a PropertyChanged event in the setter. Also you should change your binding to this new property. For example:

```
public class Wrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _value;
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value)));
        }
    }

    //INotifyPropertyChanged implementation...
}
```

Your list should be:

```
public List<MyClass> Strings { get; } = new List<MyClass>
{
    new Wrapper { Value = "Hello world1" },
    new Wrapper { Value = "Hello world2" },
    new Wrapper { Value = "Hello world3" }
};
```

and the binding should be:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: This does work, even without INotifyPropertyChanged. But I find it weird since it's still doing the same thing, the string is still immutable, just wrapped inside another class. We are still changing the string itself, now the whole reference to this class. 

Does it has something to do with how the Binding is written? `{Binding Path=.}`?

Comment: The `INotfiyPropertyChanged` part is necessary if you update the string from code and want the TextBox to show the updated value. You can omit it if you want. For the binding part, yes when you change the value in TextBox always a new string is created. However to update the list the old value must be removed and the new value should be added and this is not how binding works. When you have a wrapper class it just sets your string to the new value and discards the old value (which you cannot do with a `List`).

Comment: Ok. Why wouldn't it work tho? Doesn't the binding system know `Strings[index] = newString;` or the like?

Comment: @Frisbee, I know about immutable types. But if `<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding TheString}" />` works, why not the list? I make the TextBox in the DataTemplate bind to the corresponding string in the list the same way I bind to `TheString`. `TheString` binding works but list binding doesn't?

Comment: Wait, I think I understand now: Binding cannot change the source reference its bound to. It can only change its properties. It makes sense. 

Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: Yes, the thing is binding can change only properties, and the list items are not given as properties to the binding.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues here.

Firstly, your UI will never know if you replace the list with a new list as it will not get notified if the List<> gets re-instantiated.

Secondly, any changes to the items within the List, whether replacing the value or adding / deleting values, will go unnoticed as List does not raise change notifications.

Your best solution is a combination of the answers given by @qqww2 and @Lorek.

Move all data away from your Window class and put it in another class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Change your string collection to be ObservableCollection. 
And also raise PropertyChanged events within the setters of any properties, although this may not be required for the ObservableCollection as long as you only instantiate in the constructor and only call clear if you need to remove all the entries.

```
public class DataViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _theString;

    public DataViewModel()
    {
        Strings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Strings { get; set; }

    public string TheString
    {
        get
        {
            return _theString;
        }
        set
        {
            _theString = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TheString));
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Inside your Window class, change the constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.ViewModel = new DataViewModel();
}
```

And add a new property:

```
public DataViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
```

And change the DataContext binding on the Window tag to point to the ViewModel property.

Additional information:

On the view model, add the following method

```
public void AddString() 
{
    Strings.Add(TheString) ;
    TheString  = string.Empty;
}
```

And then call that from the button  click handler.

Comment: Doesn't work. I am updating the ListMembers using the UI and it is actually not updated in the list in reality. That's the problem.
`TheString` gets updated, but the members in the ObservableCollection doesn't.

Comment: I must be missing something, it wasn't clear from your question what you were trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 public List<string> Strings { get; } = new List<string> { "Hello world1", "Hello world2", "Hello world3" };
```

to

```
 public List<string> Strings { get; set;} = new List<string> { "Hello world1", "Hello world2", "Hello world3" };
```

Without a setter, there's no way to update that property even if it's bound.

Comment: String is RW.  List<string> Strings is not being updated - just the items.  Still worth a gving it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the type of list you are binding. Try using an ObservableCollection instead.

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Strings { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string> { "Hello world1", "Hello world2", "Hello world3" };
```

Maybe that will work.

Comment: I am actually updating the strings, not changing the collection. I gave this a try, but still does not work.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not in front if VS right now or I would have tested it first.

Comment: Here's a theory...When your Text properties change they set a new value of String, which means they create a new instance of string. The Binding points to that new String, which is not a member of the original list.  That new string is only referenced by the Binding of the TextBox. It seems this shorthand for collection-binding would only be useful if you are binding the '.' object to a UI container then binding child UI elements to properties on that object. For your super-simplistic case it fails.

Answer (score -1):

yeah, I faced with this problem too! It seems to be related to the immutable behavior of the string type. I wrote also an article with a solution on [my blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saguar/2017/03/03/the-story-of-a-in-bindable-string/).

Hope it would help :)